# Pandas Dataframe - Using index as value when slicing/filtering

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe where the index is by date string (e.g. 20161122).

I have written a basic converter to convert these strings into a datetime object and then a week number and year. and I want to create a couple of new columns that are the week number and year.  To do this, I need to refer to the index value when slicing - I've tried both methods below but they don't work (exceptions thrown).

How can I create a new column containing values derived from the index?

***Note:*** GetStats returns the pandas dataframe we're operating on.

```
stats = sf.GetStats(p, start_range, end_range)

def Index2Date__Test(i):
    dte = '2016092508'
    return parse(dte[:-2]).date()
```

Method 1:

```
stats['year'], stats['week'] = bt_utils.WeekFromDate(Index2Date__Test(stats['index']))
```

Method 2:

```
stats['year'], stats['week'] = bt_utils.WeekFromDate(Index2Date__Test(stats.index))
```

Thanks in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ***strongly*** recommend you convert your string representation to time stamps.  Make your life easier and then you can assign with conveniences like the following.  Consider the dataframe `stats`

```
stats = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(20110301, 20110311).astype(str))

# pd.to_datetime can take a format parameter that defines what to expect
stats['date'] = pd.to_datetime(stats.index, format='%Y%m%d')

# dt accessor allows you to access many convenient datetime functions
# available to columns of dtype datetime
stats['week'] = stats.date.dt.week
stats['year'] = stats.date.dt.year

print(stats)

               date  week  year
20110301 2011-03-01     9  2011
20110302 2011-03-02     9  2011
20110303 2011-03-03     9  2011
20110304 2011-03-04     9  2011
20110305 2011-03-05     9  2011
20110306 2011-03-06     9  2011
20110307 2011-03-07    10  2011
20110308 2011-03-08    10  2011
20110309 2011-03-09    10  2011
20110310 2011-03-10    10  2011
```

Comment: Sure thing.  I know to use date time stamps and not string representations.  Think I got a bit lazy not wanting to go back and update my stats dataframe generator library and was trying to accomplish it here.  The to_datetime method was a nice clean suggestion.  I have since gone back and made the adjustment and now I am able to easily access the date field when slicing/filtering/etc.  Thanks!